# Assigning ajax response to a variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var country = function () {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'url': "http://ipinfo.io",
    'success': function (data) {
      tmp = data.country;
    }
  });
  return tmp;
}();

console.log(country);
```

prints `null`

async is set to false, so it should work? What is wrong here?

BTW if I put `console.log(data.country)` inside success call it prints the country correcty

Comment: Eeeck.  Please don't use `async: false`.  That just locks up the browser and is the wrong way to program ajax calls and won't work with JSONP calls either.

Answer (score 2):

`async:false` won't work with jsonp requests.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `async` setting.

But really, you should avoid `async:false` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous.  Your country method is returning tmp before the ajax call comes back successfully.

Look into promises or deferred objects.

```
var country = function () {
    return  $.ajax({
        'dataType': 'jsonp',
        'url': "http://ipinfo.io"
    });
}

country().done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(){

});
```

Comment: any workaround for this?

Comment: @N0ir - Read the question/answers I've marked yours a duplicate of.  There is a complete explanation there as this question is asked multiple times per day.

Comment: I just took a look at the link @jfriend00 provided, great link and definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

```
var country = function () {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({    
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://ipinfo.io",
    success: function (data) {
      tmp = data.country;
    },
    async: false    
  });
  return tmp;
}();
```

Comment: So you've basically just changed `jsonp` to `json`? It would be nice to provide some textual description.